# tElm.is is not a function

Tags: jquery, angularjs, select

I have added in my html(angular.js) following script.
angular.js select2.js jquery.js etc
But it does not work well. I got following error
"TypeError: tElm.is is not a function"
How do fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

had same problem.

not only the dependencies, but also the importing sequence seems matters as well. 
try to follow what was done in the home page

```
jquery import
select2 import
angular import
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Your script sequalae write angular-ui / ui-select2 like
This will copy the ui-select2 files into your bower_components folder, along with its dependencies. Load the script files in your application:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/select2/select2.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/select2/select2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-ui-select2/src/select2.js"></script>
```

All the select2 options can be passed through the directive. You can read more about the supported list of options and what they do on the Select2 Documentation Page

```
var myAppModule = angular.module('MyApp', ['ui.select2']);
myAppModule.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
$scope.select2Options = {
allowClear:true
};
});
```

Some times it may make sense to specify the options in the template file.

```
<select ui-select2="{ allowClear: true}" ng-model="select2">
   <option value="one">First</option>
   <option value="two">Second</option>
   <option value="three">Third</option>
</select>
```

if you now more then visit the link: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2